# session value lost in asp.net in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

hai..

Am doing wepsite for show images from local drive using asp.net.am using session object for Transfer image path from first page to second page
its running nice in vs 2003 .but i converted this website to vs 2005.but session value does't pass to next page.i got null value in session object.
am using inproc session mode

kindly help me
thanks

Comment: Can you show us the faulty bit of code? Otherwise we would be just guessing at what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your application will probably encounter an error and therefore the session will end. Afterwards a new Session is started. Accessing that value in the new value will return null.

Steps to find your error:

Create the global.asax in your Rootdirectory. Set Breakpoints for Session_OnStart, Session_OnEnd and Application_OnError and try to find where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

How you are storing the path of images.
See i am doing like this and everything goes file for me.

```
Session["Path"] = @"D:\Images\PNEUMATIX_MR_CardiovascularHeart Cardiac Function_6\img.jpeg";
```

on another page i am taking like this.

```
Label1.Text = Session["Path"].ToString();
```

And i am using sessionState mode="inProc".
My be you have some problem with path.

Comment: no.. path is correct..i got session value first time of page load.but i click button after session value is lost..

Comment: first page
session["path"] = "value";
Button click ----->redirect to another page.

second page
label.Text = session["path"];

for which page you are getting session value for first time of page load.

Comment: second page i getting session value in form_load event.after i raise any event in second page i lost that value

Answer (score 0):

http://markmail.org/message/emd3swpsembfplis#query:+page:1+mid:dfdchaihfj7c46j7+state:results

Thanks god this post save my life! IE bugs with _ in the domain name .. they flush all session variable